# How can I turn a array with for to while

Tags: while-loop

```
arrayCount9([1, 2, 9]) → 1
arrayCount9([1, 9, 9]) → 2
arrayCount9([1, 9, 9, 3, 9]) → 3

public int arrayCount9(int[] nums) {
  int count = 0;
  for (int i=0; i<nums.length; i++) 
   {
    if (nums[i] == 9) {// checks if nums have 9
      count++;
    }

      return count;// gives num back
                                    }
```

I do not know how to turn this into loop.But I tried !!
Also how can I declare it in main method?
Any help!

```
while(i<nums.length) 
  { 
    if (nums[i] == 9) 
    count++; // this only counts 9s 

    i++; // you need to add this to increase your array index, otherwise 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not say which language you mean. I suggest you are programming in something Java-like. If I unterstand you correctly then you want to convert your for-loop into a while loop:

```
public static int arrayCount9(int[] nums) {
    int i = 0;
    int count = 0;
    while(i<nums.length) 
      { 
        if (nums[i] == 9) 
        count++; // this only counts 9s 

        i++; // you need to add this to increase your array index, otherwise 
    }
    return count;
}

public static void main(String args[]) { 
    int[] nums = {1, 9, 9, 3, 9};
    System.out.println(arrayCount9(nums)); //calls the upper method 
                                           //and prints the return value to console
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you indeed don't specify what language you're using. But my answer would be on java.

```
   public int arrayCount9(int[] nums) {
        int count = 0;
        int i = 0;
        while(i<nums.lenght){
            if(nums[i]==9){
                count++;
                i++;
            }
            return count;
        }
   }
```

When declaring it in main , just like this :

```
class Sample {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int nums[] = {1, 9, 9, 4, 8, 9};
        System.out.println(arrayCount9(nums));
    }
}
```